# jfrog rt mvn install: [Error] missing port in address

Tags: maven, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to build a maven project with

`jfrog rt mvn install`

and those two lines are the response:

```
[Info] Running Mvn...
[Error] missing port in address
```

I could not find any other information. How to resolve the issue, which port is meant?

I'm using jfrog-cli 1.35.3 and Artifactory Professional 6.17.0 rev 61700900.

Thanks,
Dieter

Comment: Did you create a config before using this command, as instructed [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenBuilds)? If you did, are you sure the sever you are using is configured correctly? Run jfrog rt ping to see it reaches Artifactory successfully

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm not sure which port he refers, too? The Artifactory is listening to 443 which is not specified, as the schema is https and there is also a HTTPS_PROXY variable defined with an port. So about which port is he error message talking?